# Should I pass a constant reference if all I'm passing is a single character?

Tags: c++

From what I understand, doing this:

```
bool isLetter(char c)
{
    return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z';
}

int main()
{
    char mychar = 'j';
    std::cout << isLetter(j);
    return 0;
}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
int main()
{
    char mychar = 'j';
    // ---- function procedure ----
    char temp1 = mychar;
    bool temp2 = temp1 >= 'a' && temp1 <= 'z';
    // -----------------------------
    bool mybool = temp2;
    std::cout << mybool;
    return 0;
}
```

Since the value of `c` is unmodified inside `isLetter`, I can shorten the procedure by *"passing in a constant reference"*. The `const` prefix has **no effect** on the program; it's just an agreement between the compiler and I. The reference prefix `&` is the important part because it means that the function will use the actual variable `c` rather than a copy `temp1` of it.

Hence,

```
bool isLetter(const char & c)
{
    return c >= 'a' && c <= 'z';
}

int main()
{
    char mychar = 'j';
    std::cout << isLetter(j);
    return 0;
}
```

is equivalent to

```
int main()
{
    char mychar = 'j';
    // ---- function procedure ----
    bool temp = mychar >= 'a' && mychar <= 'z';
    // -----------------------------
    bool mybool = temp;
    std::cout << mybool;
    return 0;
}
```

Well, that's my understanding.

A few questions:

- Is my understanding correct? If not, can you disabuse me of my ways?
- Is using `c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'` safe or is it bad practice since there might be some system on which ASCII values aren't sorted the usual way??
- My main question: **Is there any point of passing a constant reference when the function is such a trivial procedure???** Would a C++ programmer even bother to do that?
- Can I -- and if so, how would I -- change is function so that it returns a reference?

Thanks. I'm trying to review C++ principles because I have a job interview coming up.

Comment: There wouldn't be any difference between `const char&` and `const char` or `char`.

Comment: Don't make optimisations like this; simply write the most logical code and depend on the compiler for optimisation. In this case, you'll get the same byte code at the end anyway unless you use a terrible compiler (there are online tools you can use to verify this, but I'd recommend spending more time with the language before looking into that sort of stuff)

Comment: Rule of thumb I like to use: if it's bigger than a point pass by const reference. Otherwise, by value.

Comment: As for your last question, DON'T. The compiler is allowed to optimise return-by-value into in-place assignment, but returning by reference takes away that ability and you're likely to get *worse* performance.

Comment: And for your second question, ASCII is not system-dependant; the values between 0 and 127 are GUARANTEED. Beyond that, you're into code pages (not defined by ASCII) which could be different even between programs running on the same machine (of course, most developers use Unicode these days to avoid that; usually UTF16)

Comment: @Dave Where does the standard guarantee that ASCII is used at all? Sure, *if* ASCII is used, and it almost always is, then the values will be those defined by ASCII.

Comment: @hvd if you're working with non-ASCII data, then you can't use the `'a'` values for comparison in the first place (or at least, it would be nonsensical and confusing comparisons). I believe the char-quoted values (interpreted at compile-time) *are* defined to be ASCII

Comment: @Dave No, C++ does not require ASCII for character literals. There are implementations that do not use it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your understanding is correct.
2. If used, ASCII characters will have same ordering ( `z` will always come after `a`)
3. I guess not. Compiler will apply optimization when it sees reasonable. Besides, everything in C++ is passed by value. So the `reference` will be passed by value, and it is more overhead to copy than copying the character itself.
4. **Never** return a `pointer` or `reference` to a local variable. When the function returns, the variable will no longer exist, and the `pointer` or `reference` will be invalid, and using them will lead to **Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: @FlorisVelleman, can you please explain why not? If you pass a `pointer` to an `object` as `parameter`, the `object` will be passed by reference, but the `pointer` it self will be copied and passed **by value**

Comment: "In every system ASCII characters have same range of values" -- That's just plain wrong. Implementations are not required to use ASCII, and although other implementations are rare, they do exist.

Comment: @hvd, correct. What I meant is the ordering, not value range. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Some character codes do not have the lower case letters in a contiguous range at all (the many variants of EBCDIC are notorious for this). But it is common, and not unreasonable, to assume ASCII. Use `isalpha` etc for maximum portability.

Comment: Right, and if you're going to account for non-ASCII systems at all, EBCDIC is what you'll most likely see.